# TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression(bot)

Tags: python, sqlite, bots, telegram-bot

I am writing a bot that would make questions to users. The answers I put in the object of the class what I was created later. At the end of proceeding the user, I show the button "send answers". User press on the button and I transfer the data from the object to the database. And at that moment I get type_error:

**TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression**

I check on my object - It's not empty.
I add my code here:
main file(where I transfer user data to the database)

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'send')
def send_data_to_base():
if not db.user_exist(storage.user_id) == False:
    db.add_new_user(storage.user_id, storage.gender, storage.age, storage.salary, storage.gov_rate, 
storage.city_condition, storage.level_of_development)
```

database code:

```
import sqlite3

class SQLighter:
def __init__(self, database):
    self.connection = sqlite3.connect(database)
    self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

def get_info(self):
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `answers`").fetchall()

def user_exist(self, user_id):
    with self.connection:
        result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `answers` WHERE `user_id` = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
    return bool(len(result))

def add_new_user(self, user_id, gender, age, salary, gov_rate, city_condition, level_of_development):
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `answers` (`user_id`, `gender`, `age`, `salary`, `gov_rate`, `city_condition`, `level_of_development`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", (user_id, gender, age, salary, gov_rate, city_condition, level_of_development))
```

PS: I am using aiogram library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make my function **async** and use **await** when calling the `add_new_user` function:

```py
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='send')
async def send_data_to_base(query: CallbackQuery):
    ... 
    if not db.user_exist(storage.user_id):
        await db.add_new_user(storage.user_id, storage.gender, storage.age, storage.salary, storage.gov_rate, storage.city_condition, storage.level_of_development)
```